# I want to access iCloud drive files in iOS 7 , is this possible?

Tags: objective-c, swift, icloud, ios7.1

i know by using UIDocumentPickerViewController in iOS 8 we can access iCloud drive and read files .but for iOS 7 I searched a lot i found there is only inner app iCloud configuration. user can create doc and store it on iCLoud  but this is stored only in iCloud container related to particular app and sync with it for those created docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use iCloud Drive with iOS 7,

Here are the requirements for iCloud Drive:

> - iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iOS 8
> - Mac with OS X Yosemite
> - PC with Windows 7 or later and iCloud for Windows
> - Safari 6 or later, Firefox 22 or later, or Google Chrome 28 or later
> - An active Internet connection

Please read the FAQs on this [support article](http://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201104).

Comment: @Nitesh please accept the answer, if you feel its right answer